# Positional arguments and keyword arguments

Tags: python, compiler-errors

Why do I get an error at this Python program:

```
def student_info(**kwargs, *args):

        print(args)
        print(kwargs)


student_info(age=22, 'Hello')
```

I get the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Ioana Predi\PycharmProjects\MyProject\main.py", line 4
    def student_info(**kwargs, *args):
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: positional params/arguments always come before the keyword params/arguments

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `*args` first:

```
def student_info(*args, **kwargs):
```

This is because it is invalid to call a function or method with keyword arguments before positional arguments.